# kdevelop: comment on same line as code

Tags: ide, kdevelop, code-editor

When I type

```
some C++ code //
```

and any other symbol comment auto moves to previous line, so

```
some C++ code // comment to code
```

turns into

```
// comment to code
some C++ code
```

How can I disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure `Source Formatter`, don't forget to check both kate instruction boxes ( add and override indent mode). Then reformat your files. Now everything is fine!